# ssh daemon listening on port 22

Tags: ssh, sshd, launchd

Just curios to understand why there are many entries listening on port 22 when usually one is enough. Thanks for your time.

```
$ sudo lsof -iTCP -n -P  | grep LIST | grep 22

COMMAND    PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd      1    root   45u  IPv6 0x7f6d298ea80c2e41      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1    root   47u  IPv4 0x7f6d298ea80c75d9      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1    root   48u  IPv6 0x7f6d298ea80c2e41      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
launchd      1    root   49u  IPv4 0x7f6d298ea80c75d9      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Not sure as to why there are 4, but there are normally 2 since you need different sockets for IPv4 and IPv6. What is the output of `ps aux | grep ssh` ?

Comment: because each process has two file descriptors established (the resource is locked for read/write). IPv4 has file descriptor ID 47 and 49, and IPv6 has 45 and 48. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor if you want to look at ports, consider using `sudo netstat -ntlup | grep 22` so you are focused on ports and interfaces rather than open resources. I think the doubling may be the input and output streams SSH establishes on the port resource.

Comment: @p_q it's empty

Comment: @FrankThomas May I ask you why did you removed your answer?

Comment: Because upon further review, I'm not seeing that same pair of FDs on my ssh servers, so my answer does not fully explain the second set of file descriptors. Since the bulk of my answer was obviously going off on a tangent, it seems best to remove it for the time being.

Comment: @FrankThomas I thing you were right, the values in the fourth column (45u, 47u, 48u, 49u) are the FDs.

Comment: well, two of them are the sockets themselves (45,47), but I cannot explain the second pair (48,49). I thought I had that figured out, but my own servers are not behaving that way. they show only the first set of FDs for the sockets.